# Correct Driver For ASUS USB-AX56 WiFi Adapter

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, asus

I'm trying to track down the correct Linux driver for the ASUS USB-AX56 wifi adapter - https://wikidevi.wi-cat.ru/ASUS_USB-AX56 lists it but w/o a probable driver.

ASUS themselves claim that it's compatible with Linux but don't offer a driver download on the product page: https://www.asus.com/Networking-IoT-Servers/Adapters/All-series/USB-AX56/HelpDesk_knowledge/ only a windows driver was on the CD in the box.

I've tried various RTL drivers available online (RTL8812AU, RTL8814AU, RTL88X2BU), but none are compatible.

Any ideas where I can get drivers that will work with this?

It identifies itself as a Realtek 802.11ax adapter:

```
[  234.450494] usb 5-2.3.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0b05, idProduct=1997, bcdDevice= 
[  234.450501] usb 5-2.3.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  234.450504] usb 5-2.3.3: Product: 802.11ax WLAN Adapter
[  234.450507] usb 5-2.3.3: Manufacturer: Realtek
```

lsusb identifies it similarly:

```
Bus 005 Device 014: ID 0b05:1997 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0b05 ASUSTek Computer, Inc.
  idProduct          0x1997 
  bcdDevice            0.00
  iManufacturer           1 Realtek
  iProduct                2 802.11ax WLAN Adapter
  iSerial                 3 ---
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x004a
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           8
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              2 802.11ax WLAN Adapter
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x84  EP 4 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x05  EP 5 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x06  EP 6 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x07  EP 7 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x09  EP 9 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x0a  EP 10 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x0b  EP 11 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x0c  EP 12 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered
```

Comment: After having no luck looking up the Realtek chipset for this, I took the device apart (carefully unsoldering the shielded caps), and discovered an RTL8832AU chip.
https://imgur.com/a/tQBvU5O

Answer (score 3):

You could find the probable candidate of being included into the kernel modules package in Larry Finger's repo: [rtl8852au](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8852au)

I use it in Arch with success for several months.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! How is this better than the accepted answer that even was awarded a bounty?

Comment: @DarkDiamond , it just works. With the latest kernel. And I don't see the accepted answer, sorry. I just showed an alternative that compiles and works. Please, look at jolestar's comment. Maybe it is no longer relevant now.

Answer (score 1):

This device is very new, so drivers are rare.
ASUS only seems to supply a driver for Windows.

The article
[Using the D-Link DWA-X1850 Wi‑Fi 6 USB adapter on Linux (RTL8832AU 802.11ax)](http://sebastianschaper.net/)
seems to promise a driver for the RTL8832AU.

The driver is found on
[s-2 / RTL8852AU_WiFi_linux_v1.15.0.1-0-g487ee886.20210714](https://github.com/s-2/RTL8852AU_WiFi_linux_v1.15.0.1-0-g487ee886.20210714).
The installation is done via `make` and then `sudo make instal`.
Re-plug the dongle (or reboot) for it to be used.

Comment: I try to compile the driver and fix a compile error for new Linux kernel version at https://github.com/jolestar/RTL8852AU_WiFi_linux_v1.15.0.1-0-g487ee886.20210714  and then make and install it. but it still do not work.